# Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, .net-5, ml.net

To some unknown reason, I get this error whenever i try to run my **console app (C#)**. I use **Visual Studio 2019 (for Mac)**. I tried reinstalling **"fontconfig"** using **"brew"**, however it did not help me. Could you please tell me how to fix it?

[image]